# Visual Studio cordova project not give the same results with cordova cli project. Why?

Tags: android, cordova, ocr, tesseract, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to use Tesseract OCR with cordova on Visual Studio(for Android). With Cordova CLI,Create a project, then I am running. I'm getting accurate data without any problems.But when I do the same process with Visual Studio , containing two or more lines of text does not read.Returns absurd values(ex: mmm->uuu mmjmmm) 
I can only read a single line of data.

How can fix this problem.That is my code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, options);
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        int rotate = 0;

        switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            rotate = 180;
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            rotate = 270;
            break;
        }
        if (rotate != 0) {

            // Getting width & height of the given image.
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            // Setting pre rotate
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.preRotate(rotate);

            // Rotating Bitmap
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
        }
        // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
    baseApi.setDebug(true);
    baseApi.setPageSegMode(1);
    baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
    baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

    String recognizedText = "";
    recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast.makeText(this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),recognizedText, duration).show();
    baseApi.end();
    recognizedText = recognizedText.trim();
    return recognizedText;
```

I've used this picture(with camera)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5zGA.jpg

Comment: Yes i am using same image both platforms. For example this. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/OCR-Chain-Code/image012.jpg

Comment: I can pick and choose through the images to phone, or I can do it using the camera. The situation is, single-line text appears correctly but when two or more lines, projects in visual studio shows nonsensical values. I add up the code.

Comment: If you want people to be able to replicate your results, you should post *one* image representative of the problem, your result for that image on both platforms, and your expected result.

Comment: Have you tried other page segmentation modes?

Comment: Yeah I tried. Continued the same problem. I added the picture I used above. But I can not add the others (my reputation was not enough). Results in the following ;  http://i.stack.imgur.com/VrgeG.png     and   http://i.stack.imgur.com/iHO2b.png   .

Comment: @rmtheis; I solved the problem. I think that the problem ocr library, but it was not. Visual Studio was using the old camera plugins.So none of the pictures I took with Visual Studio can not read properly(the same result in two projects). But when I add the camera plugin the latest version of cordova cli , it was working smoothly. Thanks you for your interest and help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. To potentially help others, you should add your explanation about the camera plugin as an answer and accept it by checking the green check mark next to your answer.

Comment: @rmtheis; I want to ask you a question about tesstwo. Tesseract using the iOS side had a function that converts images to black and white.Example; tesseract.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_sample.jpg"] g8_blackAndWhite] . Is tesstwo already doing it? or is there a function which does this work? Because I could not find how true black and white(not grayscale) picture of java is obtained

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for me to know for sure without a code sample, but it's possible that when you're creating a new project via the CLI, you're creating a project using a different version number.

```
$ cordova create myProject
```

... will create a project using the most recent version of Cordova available. As of this writing, that's version 5.0

However, Visual Studio 2015 RC will create a Cordova 4.3 project by default. To change the version number, open config.xml and change the Cordova CLI version number to "5.0" under the "Platforms" tab.

You can also open projects created by the CLI in Visual Studio by adding taco.json to the project root. The file only needs to include a single json key/value pair with the correct version of the CLI that you're using:

```
{
"cordova-cli": "5.0.0"
}
```

You can also opt to instead use Cordova 4.3.0 from the command line by using this to install:

```
npm install -g cordova@4.3.0
```

5.0.0 is a major revision to Cordova so there are a number of changes.

Comment: My visual studio not have platforms tab. I saw that on the internet, but for some reason not in mine.